# How to generate a client certificate using a third party CA-NOT Self Signed CA

Tags: apache, openssl, ssl-certificate, httpd.conf

I am trying to trying to export a client certificate for use with a web browser.

The goal is to restrict access using the <Location> directive to the admin area.  I have seen numerous tutorials on using self signed CAs.  How would you do this using a third party?

1) Do I need to include the CA in the client pfx if it is a trusted root CA?  I have seen both examples.

Without CA:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey KEYFILENAME -in CERTFILEFILENAME -out XXX.pfx
```

With CA:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export  -in my.crt- inkey my.key -certfile my.bundle -out my.pfx
```

2) Do I need to still include SSLCACertificateFile for trusted CA in the httpd.conf setup?

```
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLCACertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/ca.crt
<Location /secure/area>
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1
</Location>
```

http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.8/ssl_howto.html#ToC8

Comment: This doesn't require programming. You might have better luck on serverfault.

Comment: Definitely a serverfault question, voted to move.

Answer (score 5):

You can not issue client certificates with third party CA signed certificate. You have to have self signed CA for issuing of client certificates and specify this CA as `SSLCACertificateFile`

Sample:

```
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.cer # site certificate signed by verisign
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key # site key for certificate signed by verisign
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apachelca2.pem # your self signed CA
```

note that `apachelca2.pem` has both key and certificate in it... command lines to issue client certificates:

```
openssl req -config /usr/share/apache2/ssleay.cnf -new -key client.key -out client.csr

openssl x509 -req -days 365 -CA /etc/apache2/ssl/apachelca2.pem -CAkey /etc/apache2/ssl/apachelca2.pem -CAcreateserial -in client.csr -extfile /usr/share/apache2/ssleay.cnf -extensions v3_req -out client.crt
```